# How to apply function to object attribute for every row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a table in pandas where each row is an object with attributes. Each object looks like

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '0400000US23',
  'STATE': '23',
  'NAME': 'Maine',
  'LSAD': '',
  'CENSUSAREA': 30842.923}}
```

I want to go over each row and add one more attribute called `TERPS` to the `properties` dictionary, so that it looks like

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '0400000US23',
  'STATE': '23',
  'NAME': 'Maine',
  'LSAD': '',
  'CENSUSAREA': 30842.923,
  'TERPS': 82}}                   <----- new attribute
```

The value for the `TERPS` attribute should come from another dictionary `counts`, which looks like

```
California              1161
New York                 601
Florida                  588
Minnesota                533
Maryland                 463
Washington               438
Texas                    363
Pennsylvania             356
Ohio                     348
```

I can do this for one row:

```
df.iloc[0]['properties']['TERPS'] = counts[df.iloc[0]['properties']['NAME']]
```

But how do I do this for all rows? This will get the value for every row, but I'm struggling with assigning it.

```
df.apply(lambda x : counts[x['properties']['NAME']], axis=1)
```

Comment: `lambda x: x['properties']['TERPS'] = counts[x['properties']['NAME']]` ?

Comment: that throws 'lambda cannot contain assignment" error

Comment: could you share the pandas dataframe, with the expected output. you possibly could add the extra detail without iterating over each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `=` in `lambda` but you can do this in function which you can use with `apply()`.

```
def change(x):
    x['properties']['TERPS'] = counts[x['properties']['NAME']]

df.apply(change)
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

counts = {'Maine': 83}

data = {'A': [{'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'GEO_ID': '0400000US23',
  'STATE': '23',
  'NAME': 'Maine',
  'LSAD': '',
  'CENSUSAREA': 30842.923}}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def change(x):
    x['properties']['TERPS'] = counts[x['properties']['NAME']]

df['A'].apply(change)

print(df['A'].iloc[0]['properties'])
```